# Algorithm to find maximum of combinations of arrays

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have `n` finite arrays `A[n]`, and the elements in those arrays are ordered pair `(p,r)` where `0 < p < 1` and `r` is a real number.

For instance,`A[n][elements][0] = p`,`A[n][elements][1] = r`

Let C = `{p[1]*p[2] *...*p[n] * (r[1] + ...+ r[n]): where (p[i],r[i]) are in distinct arrays from A[n]}` and I would like to find the maximum/minimum `m` elements of it.

Is there any algorithm that has order of any combinations of `m` and `n`, but not the actual size of the arrays in `A[n]`?

Example: say n = 2, m = 2, A[1] = {(0.23,91.2),(0.45,-31.7),(0.32,60.5)} and A[2] = {(0.12,150.3),(0.26,13.3),(0.33,200.3),(0.29,-23.4)}.

The 2 maximum is given by 0.32*0.33*(60.5+200.3)=27.54 and 0.45*0.33*(-31.7+200.3)=25.04.

The 2 minimum is given by 0.45*0.28*(-31.7+-23.4)=-7.19 and 0.45*0.26*(-31.7+13.3)=-2.15.

Comment: I believe this is called a permutation

Comment: Declared notation suggest that set C has only one element if n is defined. Are you sure that you've described problem properly?

Comment: I thought permutation concerns the ordering of the element in a single set, so it may not suit here. But I think I need a more concise description than "combinations of arrays".

Comment: A_is are sets with possibly more than one elements and for each element in product of A_is, we have a function that maps the element to C. So C should have more than 1 elements in general. Is there any way I can describe it better?

Comment: So `C` appears to be calculated by picking one element from each array in `A`. If you want to minimise or maximise `C` by picking different elements, I'm still with you, but where does `m` come into play?

Comment: Instead of picking the top element, I would like to have top m elements of C.

Comment: "Is there any algorithm that has order of any combinations of m and n" - this kind of sounds like you want to get all possible combinations, and then loop over them to find the best ones (which is a somewhat trivial and inefficient way to solve the problem), while it might be possible to more efficiently solve this problem without doing that. It's entirely possible that I'm misunderstand what you're trying to say.

Comment: There are 3 kinds of dimension here, number of arrays n, number of top elements chosen m and finally the size of the arrays A[i] itself. The problem I encounter is that the (product of) sizes of the arrays A[i] are not manageable, so brute force search is not possible. Therefore, I would like the order of the algorithm to be dependent on m and n only.

Comment: I think you should give a small example to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: What's the range of `r`? Can it be negative?

Comment: A short example is added! Yes, r can be negative.